# Can I produce both jar and war of a project in maven?

Tags: maven

I have a project(A) in maven that has packaging of war. One other project(B) depends on A and it needs project A jar file but in phase of compile, the war of project A will produce and no jar is available for project B.
How can I create a jar of project A in phase of compile so that project B can use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution : :)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-a-jar</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <file>
                            ${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar
                        </file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I would say you found a hack but not a solution ;-)

Comment: I agree with khmarbaise. Using the 'attachClasses' option of the war-plugin is much cleaner. By default, it also appends -classes to the artifact (similar to sources and javadoc) to make it clear this is not the primary output from the module.

Of course it might be better to create a new module that is common to the war project as well as the other project. All depends on specific situation.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to go a different way and use the [maven-war-plugin which can produce a separate artifact for the classes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses) which can be used like the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>myVersion</myVersion>
  <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

This can be achieved by using the following configuration in your war module:

```
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
```